# Cannot install my NodeJs project using `npm init`

Tags: node.js, project, package.json

```
C:\Users\dell>npm install
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\dell/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\dell\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-12T20_24_02_026Z-debug-0.log

C:\Users\dell>npm install
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\dell/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\dell\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-12T20_24_02_026Z-debug-0.log
```

How can I resolve these errors?

Comment: Well, does the file `C:\Users\dell\package.json` exist?

Comment: run npm install inside your projects' path

Answer (score 0):

To install something you first need to have a project i. e. there must be a `package.json` file.

So if you want to install some existing project you need to get hold of that `project.json` file, place it in a directory and then from within that directory run `npm install` and the project will be installed as specified in the `package.json`.

If you want to start with a new project you first need to create and initialize the project. You can do that by running the following commands

- create directory for your project

```
mkdir MyProject
```

- switch to that directory

```
cd MyProject
```

- initialize the project

```
npm init
```

After running `npm init` you will be asked some question like project name etc. which you need to fill out. Then you have a project and can install packages using `npm install <package-name>` which will add the package to your `package.json`.

See also:

- [nodesource - The Basics of Package.json](https://nodesource.com/blog/the-basics-of-package-json)
- [w3schools - What is npm?](https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_npm.asp)